# Vert.x: Extend timeout of specific routes

Tags: vert.x

I use an `io.vertx.ext.web.openapi.RouterBuilder` to route operations of an OpenAPI spec to the Eventbus:

```
RouterBuilder.create(vertx, openapiFile).onSuccess(routerBuilder -> {
  for (Operation operation : routerBuilder.operations())
    operation.routeToEventBus(operation.getOperationId());
});
```

I attach it to my `Router`

```
router.route("/api/*").subRouter(routerBuilder.createRouter());
```

and create a worker verticle to consume the messages and reply the results as `ServiceResponse`

```
 EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();
 eb.consumer("some_id", msg -> {
   msg.reply(ServiceResponse.completedWithPlainText(null).toJson());
 });
```

Some operations take pretty long and I deploy the worker verticles with an extended execute time

```
new DeploymentOptions().setMaxWorkerExecuteTime(180_000).setMaxWorkerExecuteTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

My Problem is the routing context. It `times out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply`. The worker works just fine also after the 30000(ms).

How can I extend the timeout in general or (even better) for routes where I know that those can take longer than expected? Bonus: Where in Vert.x is the default timeout of 30_000 ms set? I didn't found it.

I tried with a [TimeoutHandler](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/TimeoutHandler.html) but without success.

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the send timeout via the DeliveryOptions:

```
operation.routeToEventBus(operation.getOperationId(), new DeliveryOptions().setSendTimeout(180_000));
```